# Como retornar um Json puro (sem encapsulamento XML) usando webservice em c#

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, web-service, encapsulamento

Estou com um **webservice rodando localmente**, que realiza consultas diretamente em um banco de dados por meio de **um parâmetro do tipo string**. Segue o resultado da consulta:

[image: Retorno encapsulado]
A segundo momento tenho uma aplicação em **javascript (Jquery)** que consome o **webservice via Ajax**. Após algumas pesquisas cheguei a conclusão que o problema é o **encapsulamento XML**, pois estou tentando consumir o **Json via Ajax.**

Aplicação Jquery tentando consumir wbeservice c# via Ajax:

```
$("#btnConsultar").on("click",function(){

            var NTalao = $("#campoTalao").val();


            $.ajax({

                url: "...",
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: {"Talao": NTalao},
                success: function(data){
                    $("#resDIV").html(data);

                },
                error: function(){
                alert("Erro!");
                }
            });

        });
```

Webservice c# retornando Json encapsulado:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    [WebMethod]
    public string Consultar(string _Talao)
    {

        Model1 cadastro = new Model1();
        clsRecibo recibo = new clsRecibo();

        var consulta = from a in cadastro.TB_Recibo
                       where a.Talao == _Talao
                       select a;


        foreach (var linha in consulta)
        {
            recibo.Talao = linha.Talao;
            recibo.Apresentante = linha.Apresentante;
            recibo.TipoServico = linha.TipoServico;
            recibo.Status = linha.Status;
            recibo.Obs = linha.Obs;
        }

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        return js.Serialize(recibo);

    }
```

**Pergunta base:** É possível retirar esse encapsulamento XML da consulta?? Caso contrário, consigo efetuar a consulta pelo aplicativo de outra forma?

Obrigado!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hudson, modifique o método para void e retorne da seguinte forma:

```
 HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(js.Serialize(recibo));
 HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Comment: Realizei essas alterações e o webservice retornou um Json puro, porém ainda não consigo consumi-lo via Ajax, no app. Será que pode ser a url? Estou consultando localmente... urls já testadas: `http://localhost:50318/ServiceCRI.asmx/Consultar`,

Comment: Hudson, veja se pode ser referente a sua chamada ajax, aconteceu comigo erro no cabeçalho da requisição http: Access-Control-Allow-Headers, resolvi isso retirando o content-type da chamada ajax no client side

De toda forma, veja se no seu teste local aparece algum erro no console

Answer (score 2):

Para que o atributo `ScriptMethod` seja interpretado, você precisa garantir que o módulo `System.Web.Extensions` seja carregado.

Duas alterações na sessão `system.web` no seu `web.config` são necessárias:

```
<assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
</assemblies>

<httpHandlers>
    <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory" validate="false"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

[Post original no SO em Inglês.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9470746/1845714)